# How to count a occurrence in a dataframe in R, without repetition

Tags: r, data-science, data-analysis

I have a question, I'm learning to use `group_by()` and `summarise()` in the R. But, I stopped at a question in the book I'm studying.

Follow: "How many senators did each party have? Which one had more? Which ones had the least? Tip use: `group_by ()`, `summarize ()` and `n_distinct ()`"

The data set seems like it's:

[image]

I have tried to do like this:

```
    senators <- senado %>% group_by(Party) %>% summarise(num_senators = n_distinct(senado$SenatorUpper))
```

But, I don't have success.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: *"but, I don't have success"* ... errors, warnings, or incorrect output would be best shown to use (verbatim). If just incorrect output, it might still be informative. (More-so because we don't have sample data on which we can try the code ourselves.)

Comment: Don't use `$` in `dplyr` pipes . Try `senado %>% group_by(Party) %>% summarise(num_senators = n_distinct(SenatorUpper))`